# Multiple Textbox Validations

Tags: c#, validation, textbox

So I have a form with many `TextBox-es` which all need to be filled in. I have researched textbox validation but I can only find instructions for validating singular text boxes. Below is the code I have for the singular textbox validation. I was just wondering if it possible to hit all of them at once instead of this for each one. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
private void txtName_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text.Trim()))
    {
        epName.SetError(txtName, "Name is required.");
    }
    else
    {
        epName.SetError(txtName, string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58899390/c-sharp-error-provider-not-working-on-textboxes-in-groupbox-and-tabcontrols/58900066#58900066) if the `TextBox-es` are hosted by different containers.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using `WinForms`

```
// Get all the controls of the forms
var controls = this.Controls;
foreach (Control mycontrol in controls)
{
    // Check if the Control is a TextBox
    if (mycontrol is TextBox)
    {
     //Perform Operation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var controls = this.Controls;
        foreach (Control mycontrol in controls)
        {
            // Check if the Control is a TextBox
            if (mycontrol is TextBox)
            {
                epname.seterror(mycontrol, mycontrol+"is required");
            }
        }
```

Comment: It would be beneficial to not just copy my answer but innovate it. Like for example a better way to get Controls or improving the foreach loop. So that the OP can benefit from it